# All Pods not recognized after starting the process of adding to app store 'No such module' error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

My app worked just fine until I started the process to upload to the app store and somewhere during that process, I started getting the error 'No such module'.

I have tried different pods, same result
I have tried a new blank project with just the import line (after importing the pod), same result

After eliminating the pod it self and the project, it has got to be a setting that got changed that won't allow it to see the pod files.  If anybody has any thoughts, I would be greatly appreciative.

*edit: Taking Dershowitz123's advice, I have tried changing the path for the frameworks to

```
    $(SRCROOT)
```

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8eoA.png) (sry, I don't have the reputation to post embedded images yet).

I still get a failed build, but I think you are in the right direction.  I noticed that it isn't finding the framework file.

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNr5L.png)

I've looked for the file listed and I don't see one in the directory anywhere.  When I made my blank test project, it also didn't create a Pods_RiskAssement.framework file (or similar named file).

*edit 2

here's my Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '8.0'
    # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
    use_frameworks!

    target ‘RiskAssement’ do

    pod ‘SimplePDF’

    end
```

*edit

Resolution.  I was unable to figure out how to import the pod, but was able to copy the swift file data and embed it directly into the code for my app.  This way I didn't need to reference the pod and was able to build the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is actually happens, but one way to solve your issue is to go into your build settings and defining the Framework Search Paths to a folder which contains the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to `$(SRCROOT)` and set it to recursive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I think you are in the right direction, that still didn't do it though.  I edited my original post to include the new steps taken.

Comment: Please run `pod update` and check once. And Paste your `Podfile` here so that I can see if you've done that correctly.

Comment: I ran pod update and got the same result.  Here's my Podfile :                   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target ‘RiskAssement’ do

pod ‘SimplePDF’

end

Answer (score 0):

I recently received the same 'No such module' message for the different PODS that I had installed. The resolution for me was to select the PODS project in my workspace, select all of my targets, and then manually build them using either the menu command or the Command B shortcut. After it finished building the errors went away.

I hope it helps!